# Mono trace filtering

Tags: debugging, mono

You can use the Mono `--trace` option to make Mono trace execution to the console. But trying to control what gets traced is an exercise in frustration! How do I make it only trace *my* code?

You would *think* that this works:

```
mono --trace=N:MyApp MyApp.Main.exe
```

However, this only shows stuff *in the root* of the `MyApp` namespace. It does *not* show all the namespaces below this. How do I add this critically necessary wildcard? This is a vast application with several thousand nested namespaces!

My first thought was to use a star, but Mono seems to not like that. My next thought was to do `--trace=-N:System`. But that only excludes *the root of* the `System` namespace, not the dozens of namespaces under it. So, almost exactly the same problem again!

Is there seriously no way to achieve this trivial little task? Surely I can't be the first person to want to trace a group of related namespaces...

(The application consists of two-dozen DLLs, so limiting it by DLL won't really help either.)

Comment: 'several thousand nested namespaces'? really?... in that case, doing it by assembly would be your best option, assign a env. var with your 24  assemblies and use that in your -trace= option.